# Best practices for generating and storing authorization codes and access tokens in OAuth server

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth2, uuid

I've recently implemented an OAuth server functionality to our service. I've consulted [OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-3.4) and addressed most of the concerns. I am curious about any best practices for generating authorization **code** and **access_token**.

Our backend is written in Node.js, so I am using **[uuid v4](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid)** for both codes and access tokens. Historically, I've seen code's to be shorter than uuid v4, around 6-8 characters long. And recently, I've seen [tokens in Slack API](https://api.slack.com/authentication/token-types#user) be likely something else.

Now, I know uuid is considered to be *unguessable*, we also use a code only one time, and the code is short-lived. Is there anything else that can improve the quality (or unguessability) of the codes and access tokens?

Additionally, does it make sense to hash the codes and access tokens inside database? What is the optimal hash function for it? Right now we use `sha256` in similar places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've been advised that UUID is [not considered to be secure enough](https://littlemaninmyhead.wordpress.com/2015/11/22/cautionary-note-uuids-should-generally-not-be-used-for-authentication-tokens/), although practically it should be.

So in Node/JS world it's better to use `secure` module instead of `uuid.v4()`. More specifically:

```
crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex')
```

But this is a general discussion about UUID, not sure if there are extra requirements for OAuth stuff. I wouldn't say so.